# Determine if a function is a total derivative

Tags: derivatives

Lagrangian is defined up to addition of a total derivative of function of positions and time. Now suppose we have a function $f(x,\dot x,t)$. How can one show (check) that
$$\not\exists g(x,t):\; f(x,\dot x,t)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}g(x,t)$$
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$\frac{d}{dt}g(x,t)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \dot{x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$$
$g$ exists iff $f$ is linear in $\dot{x}$, 
$$f(x,\dot{x},t)=f_1(x,t)\dot{x}+f_2(x,t)$$
and moreover
$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}$$
(if there are several $x$'s, there are more conditions, but they still say that the 2nd partial derivatives of $g$ are symmetric).